# Multiple Nested Loops and Arrays, SubScript out of range

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

Still getting used to handling arrays and loops. Would someone mind pointing out the issue with this?

To go over it, its a simple loops that checks a1:a100 in sheet one and checks it against b1:b100 in each sheet then returns the count of it in Sheet1!c1:c100

thanks in advance

```
 Private Sub TheLoops()

 Dim SearchArray()
 Dim SheetArray()
 Dim ColumArray()
 Dim ReturnArray()
 Dim ModCount As Long
 SearchArray = Sheet1.Range("a1:a100")
 SheetArray(0) = Sheet1
 SheetArray(1) = Sheet2
 SheetArray(2) = Sheet3
 ColumArray = ActiveSheet.Range("b1:b100")
 ReturnArray = Sheet1.Range("c1:c100")
 ModCount = 0

 For I = LBound(SearchArray) To UBound(SearchArray)
     For L = LBound(ReturnArray) To UBound(ReturnArray)
         For J = LBound(SheetArray) To UBound(SheetArray)
             For K = LBound(ColumArray) To UBound(ColumArray)
                 If SearchArray(I) = ColumArray(K) Then
                     ModCount = ModCount + 1
                 End If
             Next K
         Next J
     ReturnArray(L) = ModCount
     ModCount = 0
     Next L
 Next I

 End Sub
```

Is this correct?

```
 SearchArray = Sheet1.Range("a1:a100").Value, LBound(SearchArray, 1)

 For I = SearchArray(I, LBound(SearchArray, 2)) to SearchArray(I, UBound(SearchArray, 2))

 etc etc etc
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem is down to `.Range` having a default property called `Value` that returns a two dimensional `Variant`. This is incompatible with the type you are assigning that to.

Use `Dim SearchArray as Variant`, `SearchArray = Sheet1.Range("a1:a100").Value`, `LBound(SearchArray, 1)` followed by two dimensional indexing: `SearchArray(I, LBound(SearchArray, 2))`.

Refactor the other variables in a similar way.

Comment: Ok maybe im not following.... but essentially what youre saying redeclare variables and then when I announce the loop I have to restructure what it needs to go through? Sorry I just want to make sure I am understanding correctly

Comment: Not entirely, you need to replace you declaration with what I have, along with the assignments, and the LBound and UBound functions.

Comment: I posted and a sample edit to see if I understood you correctly. Is that correct?